# Comparing 2 two-dimensional arrays JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, compare

Okay, here's how the program should work:
By running the program, it will ask the user to input number of players that will play the Lotto. For example, 3. So 3 rows of array would be made and 6 column which is default column. Now after generating random digits in Lotto array. It will then generate a winning Lotto.

The problem is here:
Ive done the part of generating the player's lotto and the winning lotto. However, I cant compare winning lotto to players lotto/s. For example:

Player 0 : 1 15 30 41 56 12

Player 1: 31 65 78 43 29 8

Player 2: 41 28 1 6 38 14

Winning Lotto: 15 30 56 12 41 1

The winner should be the Player 0 even the sorting is not exact. 
But the problem is I cant compare the two dimensional arrays.

Here's the code:

`import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;


public class test{
    public static void main(String asd[]){

            int players = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Any NUMBER of PLAYERS\n[0] to exit"));
            while(players != 0)
            {
                int typeOfLotto = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Type:\n[42] - SixFortyTwo\n[45] - SixFortyFive\n" + 
                                                                "[49] - SixFortyNine\n[55] - SixFiftyFive"));
                String output="", playersLotto="", winning="";
                int taya = 6;
                int index;
                int[][] Lotto = new int[players][taya];
                int[][] winningLotto = new int[1][taya];
                for(index = 0; index<players; index++)
                {
                    for(int column = 0; column<6; column++)
                    {
                        Lotto[index][column] = numberGen(typeOfLotto,Lotto,index);
                        output += Lotto[index][column] + " ";
                    }
                    playersLotto += "Player " + index + ": " + output +"\n";
                    output="";
                }



                //winning lotto
                for(int column = 0; column<6; column++)
                {
                    winningLotto[0][column] = winningNumberGen(typeOfLotto,winningLotto);
                    winning += winningLotto[0][column] + " ";
                    if(column==5)
                        winning = "Winning lotto: " + winning;
                }


                String win = checking(Lotto,winningLotto,players);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, playersLotto + "\n" + winning + "\n" + win);
                players = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Any NUMBER of PLAYERS\n[0] to exit"));
            }










    }

    public static int numberGen(int typeOfLotto,int Lotto[][],int index)
    {

        int random=0, loop=0;
        if(typeOfLotto == 42)
        {
            random = (int)(1+Math.random()*42);
                for(loop=0; loop<6; loop++)
                {
                    if(Lotto[index][loop] == random)
                        return numberGen(typeOfLotto,Lotto,index);
                }
        }

        return random;
    }
    //winning
    public static int winningNumberGen(int typeOfLotto,int winningLotto[][])
    {

        int random=0, loop=0;
        if(typeOfLotto == 42)
        {
            random = (int)(1+Math.random()*42);
                for(loop=0; loop<6; loop++)
                {
                    if(winningLotto[0][loop] == random)
                        return winningNumberGen(typeOfLotto,winningLotto);
                }
        }

        return random;
    }


    public static String checking(int Lotto[][], int winningLotto[][], int players)
    {
        int win[] = new int[6];
        int panalo=0;
        String winner="", output="";
        for(int index=0; index<players;index++)
        {
            for(int loop=0;loop<6;loop++)
            {

                if(winningLotto[0][0] == Lotto[index][loop])
                    win[loop] = Lotto[index][loop];
                if(winningLotto[0][1] == Lotto[index][loop])
                    win[loop] = Lotto[index][loop];
                if(winningLotto[0][2] == Lotto[index][loop])
                    win[loop] = Lotto[index][loop];
                if(winningLotto[0][3] == Lotto[index][loop])
                    win[loop] = Lotto[index][loop];
                if(winningLotto[0][4] == Lotto[index][loop])
                    win[loop] = Lotto[index][loop];
                if(winningLotto[0][5] == Lotto[index][loop])
                    win[loop] = Lotto[index][loop];
            }

        }

        if(win[0] > 0)
            panalo++;
        if(win[1] > 0)
            panalo++;
        if(win[2] > 0)
            panalo++;
        if(win[3] > 0)
            panalo++;
        if(win[4] > 0)
            panalo++;
        if(win[5] > 0)
            panalo++;


        if(panalo > 3)
        {
            for(int loop=0;loop<6;loop++)
            {
                winner += win[loop] + " ";
            }
            output = "Winner: " + winner;
        }
        else if(panalo < 3)
            output = "no winner";   

        return output;
    }

}`

I dont have a lot of knowledge about java since Im still a 1st year college. So can I ask simple codes? I want to do the comparing in for loops. I only know basic. I hope the most simple code can do.

**UPDATED** ADDED 1 METHOD FOR CHECKING IT WORKS FOR 1 PLAYER BUT DOESNT IN MORE THAN 1.

**UPDATE** answered it myself.

Answer (score 1):

First sort winning lotto

```
Arrays.sort(winninglotto);
```

then for each of your players get the numbers array sort it and then see if they are equal to winning lotto

```
Arrays.sort(playernumbers);
return Arrays.equals(playernumbers, winninglotto);
```

like this:

```
public static String checking(int Lotto[][], int winningLotto[][], int players)
{
 Arrays.sort(winningLotto[0]);
 for(int i =0; i < players;i++){
     Arrays.sort(Lotto[i]);
    if(Arrays.equals(Lotto[i], winningLotto[0])){
       //we have a winnder
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Am I applying this to main or I will create a new method?

Comment: And also how to sort the Lotto array's lotto numbers.